# Subtracting two HTML fields and showing result asap JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am not very experienced in JS. I have two fields for input in HTML in which the first user enters amount to withdraw and datas goes into JavaScript, it subtracts 0.00200000 and show it in second HTML input field (readonly field):-
Html:-

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('ant').value; 
  var myBox2 = 0.00200000;
  var result = document.getElementById('bank').value; 
  var numb = myBox1 - myBox2;
  numb = numb.toFixed(8);
  result.value = numb;
}
```

```html
      <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
      <p>Amount</p><input class="input100" type="text" name="amount" id="ant" placeholder="Amount to Send" oninput="calculate()">
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      <span class="symbol-input100">
      </span>
     </div>
                        <span class="login100-form-title">
     Tx Fee:-0.00200000 LiteCoin (LTC)
     </span>
                    <br>Your receive: - <input class="input100" type="text" id="bank" placeholder="Amount you receive" oninput="calculate()" readonly>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Withdraw">
```

When I put value in 1st input field in my page second field never gets any value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small mistake:

```
var result = document.getElementById('bank').value;
```

needs to be

```
var result = document.getElementById('bank');
```

`result` need to represent the element itself, not its value. Otherwise you can't then change its value.

Strictly you also ought to use `parseFloat()` to avoid JS thinking the value from your "ant" textbox is a string and treating it as such. Luckily in this case you're operating against a fixed value, but if you'd tried to subtract two textbox values (both strings) you'd have had a bigger issue.

Also `oninput="calculate()"` in the "bank" element is redundant. Since the field is read only, there can never be any user input to trigger the function.

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ant').value);
  var myBox2 = 0.00200000;
  var result = document.getElementById('bank');
  var numb = myBox1 - myBox2;
  numb = numb.toFixed(8);
  result.value = numb;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <p>Amount</p><input class="input100" type="text" name="amount" id="ant" placeholder="Amount to Send" oninput="calculate()">
  <span class="focus-input100"></span>
  <span class="symbol-input100"></span>
</div>

<span class="login100-form-title">Tx Fee:-0.00200000 LiteCoin (LTC)</span>
<br>Your receive: - 
<input class="input100" type="text" id="bank" placeholder="Amount you receive" readonly>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Withdraw">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code for which second field never gets any value:

1. `document.getElementById('bank').value` should be only `document.getElementById('bank')` so that the assignment to `result` variable works for `result.value`
2. You need to use `parseFloat()` to parse the number you input in the first text box as a floating point number assuming user can input float values. This is because when you read a value from a text box using JavaScript it is considered as a `String` type and for numeric calculations you need to cast that to a valid `Number` type.

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ant').value);
  var myBox2 = 0.00200000;
  var result = document.getElementById('bank');
  var numb = myBox1 - myBox2;
  numb = numb.toFixed(8);
  result.value = numb;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <p>Amount</p><input class="input100" type="text" name="amount" id="ant" placeholder="Amount to Send" oninput="calculate()">
  <span class="focus-input100"></span>
  <span class="symbol-input100">
                    </span>
</div>
<span class="login100-form-title">
                Tx Fee:-0.00200000 LiteCoin (LTC)
                </span>
<br>Your receive: - <input class="input100" type="text" id="bank" placeholder="Amount you receive" oninput="calculate()" readonly>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Withdraw">
```

Comment: @JeffB happy to help :)